# How to copy a cursor selection range to an other sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to make a script that will copy a cursor selection range to an other sheet, script is partially working

The script is coping some values, some of the values selected from the target sheet

```
     function copy(){

   var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
   var range = ss.getActiveRange();
   var srange = range.getA1Notation();
   var crange= ss.getRange(srange);
   var data = crange.getValues();



  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('id');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Tracker'); 
  ts.getRange('B16:K200').setValue(data)

}
```

The script should copy the selected value with the mouse from the selected sheet in the specified location for the target sheet

Comment: What do you mean by "partially working", are you getting any errors? Which part in particular is not working?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the Execution transcript.

Comment: the issue is that is coping the range based on much range i'm providing in the target sheet, instead of selected with the cursor

Comment: This a little difficult to follow; may I rephrase for clarification? Please correct any mistakes. You want to select a range (the source range) by highlighting cells with your cursor; the size of this range is not always the same. Then you want to copy the source range to a target range. At the moment, the target range is defined as "B16:K200", but this might be bigger or smaller than the source range. So, you want Cell "B16" to be the top left of the target range, and the actual number of rows and columns must be changed to reflect the source range.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, Yes that's exactly what I want to do, great understanding :)

Comment: @TeodorMirceaOneata If you prefix the users name with the "@" symbol, your comment will appear in their intray, and they will be notified on your comment - which is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to identify the activerange, and the relevant get row and column values. Then using "B16" as a starting point for the outout, you simply add the number of Rows and number of Columns calculated from the activerange.

Highlight any range, run the function, and the contents of the range will be copied to the same sheet with cell "B16" in the top lefthand corner.

It's a simple matter to modify the code to create the output range and copy the values to another spreadsheet.

---

```
function so5666559701() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetname = "56665597";
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  var myrange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var myvalues = myrange.getValues();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the active range = "+myrange.getA1Notation());
  var myfirstRow = myrange.getRow();
  var mylastRow = myrange.getLastRow();
  var myfirstCol = myrange.getColumn();
  var mylastCol = myrange.getLastColumn();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: details of the selectred range: row: first row="+myfirstRow+", first column="+myfirstCol+", last row="+mylastRow+" last column:"+mylastCol);

  // target cell = B16 = row 16, column 2
  var targetrange = sheet.getRange(16,2,mylastRow-myfirstRow+1,mylastCol-myfirstCol+1);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the target range = "+targetrange.getA1Notation());
  targetrange.setValues(myvalues);
}
```